# Build agent multi build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Related with the last TFS version:

Can a build agent run simultaneously n number of builds?

Sometimes my builds takes too long I wanted to know if there's some other ways plus making a new agent.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

An agent can only run one build at a time. If you want multiple builds in parallel you need multiple agents.